# Как кастомизировать сообщение при длинных числах во время валидации входящего JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, валидация

Необходимо валидировать некоторые поля с числами во входящем `JSON`. Мне нужно кастомизировать сообщение, которое возвращается, если переданное число слишком больше (больше максимального значения `long`).
Сейчас возвращается такое сообщение:

```
{
  "status": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
  "timestamp": "24.01.2020 11:31:03",
  "type": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message": "JSON parse error: Numeric value (11111111111111111111111111111111) out of range of long (-9223372036854775808 - 9223372036854775807); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Numeric value (11111111111111111111111111111111) out of range of long (-9223372036854775808 - 9223372036854775807)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 16, column: 18] (through reference chain: ru.myfirm.myproject.core.entity.SomeEntity[\"numberField\"])",
  "debugMessage": "JSON parse error: Numeric value (11111111111111111111111111111111) out of range of long (-9223372036854775808 - 9223372036854775807); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Numeric value (11111111111111111111111111111111) out of range of long (-9223372036854775808 - 9223372036854775807)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 16, column: 18] (through reference chain: ru.myfirm.myproject.core.entity.SomeEntity[\"numberField\"])",
  "subErrors": null
}
```

(это наша кастомизация вылетающих эксепшенов)

Отправляю такой `JSON`:

```
{
 ...
  "numberField": 11111111111111111111111111111111,
  ...
 }
```

Хотелось бы сообщение, как при валидации - например, такое:

```
{
  "status": "BAD_REQUEST",
  "timestamp": "24.01.2020 11:37:30",
  "type": "javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException",
  "message": "numberField: Допустимая длина поля \"название поля\": не менее 10 символов и не более 12 символов",
  "debugMessage": "numberField: Допустимая длина поля \"название поля\": не менее 10 символов и не более 12 символов",
  "subErrors": [
  ...]
  }
```

Пока, как я понимаю, мне необходимо перед десериализацией проверять длину этого поля. Это я пока ещё не нашёл (причём мне нужно это делать для конкретных запросов, а не всех, поэтому в идеале это должна быть какая-то аннотация, которая навешивается на метод контроллера).
Кроме того, значение может прийти в виде числа, а не строки, и вот это я вообще пока не понимаю, как обойти.

Answer (score 0):

Помогла смена типа поля с `Long` на `BigInteger` в самой сущности (в джава коде). Теперь прилетают обычные сообщения с `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` внутри (как я указал ниже в своём главном сообщении)